# Lotusscript check network is down?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

In an environment for a daily attendance system, the application is located in the server and on each clock-in PC (there's about 80 PC), I manually create a local replica. Each of these replica will replicate (push & pull) with the server every 1 hour. I create the replica by using the 'Make Available Offline' on the workspace. But recently, some of the clock-in PC (about 5) has network down (no connection to the server) thus can't replicate and has been causing problem to the user when they want to create reports etc because their clock-in information in the clock-in PC hasn't been replicated back to the server to be determined whether it's late-in, overtime etc.

So my question is is there any lotusscript code that I can use to write an agent that will ping each of the clock-in PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping would tell you that the PC is in the network but what you really want to know is whether the data entered on that PC is ending up to your database. A few ideas:

1. Connect the PCs directly to Domino server (no local replica). Then all network problems are immediately noticed.
2. If you need to make the app available offline then make a scheduled local agent to place a time stamp to a PC specific document. In the server database you can then check with another scheduled agent that all PCs are replicating.
3. Check the replication history of your server db. [Here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Retrieve-Databases-Replication-History) is one example.